# How do I start a multi-threaded script and exit the terminal session?

Tags: python, multithreading, background-process

I have developed a python script which is designed to run indefinitely, where the main thread fills a queue and then a series of thread process items from that queue.

If I start it from a terminal session it works as expected, as long as I leave terminal open.

If I start the script with setsid, nohup and exit the terminal session, the main thread continues but all the spawned sub threads die immediately.

To keep it simple, this is the sample code I (pinched) started with rather than my full script. Instead of the queue I have a sleep statement to keep the main thread open:

```
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime, date
from dateutil import tz

log_path = '/test_logs/'

class ThreadingExample(object):
    def __init__(self, interval=30):
        self.interval = interval

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True                            # Daemonize thread
        thread.start()                                  # Start the execution

    def run(self):
        thread_name = threading.current_thread().name

        while True:
            # Do something
            print(thread_name + ' - Doing something imporant in the background')
            time_now = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=tz.tzlocal())
            date_now = time_now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

            f = open(log_path + date_now + "_" + thread_name + ".txt", 'a')
            f.write(str(time_now) + "\t" + 'still running' + "\n")
            f.close()

            time.sleep(self.interval)

for x in range(4):
    print ("Thread {0} started.".format(x))
   # This is the thread class that we instantiate.
    example = ThreadingExample()

time.sleep(30)
print('Checkpoint')
time.sleep(50000)
print('Bye')
```

I feel I am missing something basic in either python or linux, but not sure which.

Comment: If I run the script with nohup `nohup python t.py >& /dev/null &`. threads keep running.

Comment: Thank you. That works. One follow up, is there a simple way to send what would appear in the terminal, such as any exceptions that occur, to a file?

Comment: Replace `/dev/null` to a file path. Then the file will be populated with the output of the script.